# How can I print document in cursor.ForEach?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I've defined some simple cursor as find() on some collection.

```
cursor = db.students.find()
```

Student has following schema:

```
"_id" : 19,
"name" : "Gisela Levin",
"scores" : [
        {
                "type" : "exam",
                "score" : 44.51211101958831
        },
        {
                "type" : "quiz",
                "score" : 0.6578497966368002
        },
        {
                "type" : "homework",
                "score" : 93.36341655949683
        },
        {
                "type" : "homework",
                "score" : 49.43132782777443
        }
]
```

I want to iterate cursor and print a document. I try like that:

```
cursor.forEach(function(o){print(o)})
```

It prints only this:

> [object Object]

If I modify a loop to select some simple property it works:

```
cursor.forEach(function(o){print(o._id)})
```

Though if I change it to print scores it prints this:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Is there any function to print a json document in mongodb shell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am not sure why the [`pretty`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.pretty/index.html) can't be applied to your case.

If you are consuming the cursor manually, you need to use the [`printjson`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#manually-iterate-the-cursor) function

```
db.collection.find().forEach(printjson)
```

or the following with filter expression

```
db.collection.find({}, { "scores": 1, "_id": 0 }).forEach(printjson)
```

Comment: You could also use the function `pretty`: `db.collection.find({}, { "scores": 1, "_id": 0 }).pretty()`.

Comment: Although this post is a bit older: You could also use the following notation
`db.collection.find().forEach(function(record){printjson(record.field)})`

Comment: This only apply if the you want to pretty print a single field in the document. @Tobias

Answer (score 0):

If your result set is small you can out it in a collection and then iterate over it.

```
List<org.bson.Document> resultList = (List<org.bson.Document>) mongoCollection.find()
        .into(new ArrayList<org.bson.Document>());
resultList.forEach(doc -> printJson(doc));
```

And printJson is

```
public static void printJson(org.bson.Document doc) {
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(new StringWriter(), new JsonWriterSettings(JsonMode.SHELL, true));
    new DocumentCodec().encode(jsonWriter, doc,
            EncoderContext.builder().isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true).build());
    System.out.println(jsonWriter.getWriter());
    System.out.flush();
}
```